# How to get Installed program icon on to Desktop

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. How do I run programs which are not shown in the Desktop even though they are installed? This was not the case with older version of Ubuntu 10.04. The programs would show under applications.

Comment: You searched them from dash and click on it to run.

Answer (score 1):

You should find `desktop` files of these programs. Example:

```
dpkg -L <program> | grep desktop
```

then copy the files to Your desktop (which is typically `~/Desktop`).

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this by just dragging icons from Dash to your desktop.  To
>   get started, open Dash and begin dragging your favorite apps to your
>   desktop.<sup>1</sup>

Then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/*.desktop
```

Then

```
sudo chown <username> ~/Desktop/*.desktop
```

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Add Application Shortcuts to your Desktop in Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/add-application-shortcuts-to-your-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just press the `Super+A`  Or through `Dash` on Desktop . Then browse through bottom menu Under three Horizontal Menus as `Recently used` , `Installed` and `Apps available for download`  . you can Expand the `Installed`  to view all applications.

[image]

Then in Right Corner select `Filter` as

[image]

You can Refer this [**Ubuntu Online OS Tour**](http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/en/) to get the Best out of this New release.

And also [**What's New page**](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/whats-new).